# .NET MAUI Android app config issue connecting to API, XAMARIN works

Tags: android, .net, maui

I am starting to mess around with .NET MAUI versions of a working solution I have built.

Currently in the working solution, I have a XAMARIN app that sends and grabs data from my API no issue, both locally and remotely. The app loads no problem and connects fine.

I am using the exact same API and database in my new .NET MAUI solution.  My app connects but throws a 400 error bad request after trying to create a token.

I have added the `network_security` XML entries into the app and still no go.

I have begun to take a look at the nuget packages I have on my original solution to compare them with the new solution.

Any ideas?

Here are my two calls:

```
//WORKS

{Method: POST, RequestUri: 'http://api.xxx.net/token', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent, Headers:
{
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  Content-Length: 79
}}



{StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
  Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Sun, 17 Mar 2024 18:37:42 GMT
  Pragma: no-cache
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  X-Android-Received-Millis: 1710700662659
  X-Android-Response-Source: NETWORK 200
  X-Android-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
  X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1710700662393
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  X-Powered-By-Plesk: PleskWin
  Content-Length: 541
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
  Expires: -1
}}
```

```
//DOESN'T WORK

{Method: POST, RequestUri: 'http://api.xxx.net/token', Version: 2.0, Content: System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent, Headers:
{
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  Content-Length: 78
}}

{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
  Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Sun, 17 Mar 2024 18:27:50 GMT
  Pragma: no-cache
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  X-Android-Received-Millis: 1710700070765
  X-Android-Response-Source: NETWORK 400
  X-Android-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
  X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1710700069943
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  X-Powered-By-Plesk: PleskWin
  Content-Length: 82
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
  Expires: -1
}}
```

Comment: the 400 response is from the server, not the app.  What do the logs show?

Comment: Hi Jason, Yeah I know the response is coming from the server, it's just that it is the exact same api call being made from the same machine, just a different app is the only difference.  I am getting my host provider to enable my logging on the api.  Chat here soon! Cheers

Comment: Hi Jason.  I figured it out.   First off, the requests above are backwards, the top one is the one that did not work and vice versa.  It was adding an extra character at the end.  Turns out I forgot to add the TRIM() on the field grab.  Thanks again.

Comment: I wondered why the `Content-Length` values were different